# How to Screen Record on Samsung Galaxy A30s

Tags: samsung, screencast

My goal is to record my screen. Coming from a Huawei, I would have in the upper area icons an option with "Screen Record". I'm now using a Galaxy A30s with Android 10 and these are the only options available

[image: Page one]

and

[image: Page two]

So, no screen record.

If I go to Settings and search for "screen record",

[image: No results found]

If I search under apps,

[image: No current option]

How should I do it?

---

### Edit

As pointed by [Robert](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/2241/robert), I tried to enable the screen recorder via adb but didn't get the desired result.

1. [Download Platform Tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools) and unzip the folder in location of your choice
2. Open Command Prompt in that location

[image: Platform Tools]

3. Connect the phone with the computer allowing USB Debugging
4. Run

   adb shell settings put global settings_screenrecord_long_press true

[image: adb screenrecord_long_press]

and this opens up the following in the phone

[image: Allow or not cancel]

5. Click "Allow" and run the command again

[image: No error this time]

and appears to be working.

6. Long press power button. This is what I see

[image: Long press power button]

So, still no option to record screen. I restarted the phone as well just in case but that wasn't enough either.

Comment: What Android version is installed on your device?

Comment: @Robert Android version 10

Comment: Have you tried to enable the screen recorder via `adb`?: `adb shell settings put global settings_screenrecord_long_press true`

Comment: @Robert I haven't, didn't know about it

Comment: Afterwards the screen recording function should show-up in the power menu (long press the power button to show this menu).

Comment: Just tested it @Robert but didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Android 11 announcement page](https://www.android.com/android-11/), we can expect a Built-in screen recording

> Screen recording lets you capture what’s happening on your phone. And
> it’s built right into Android 11, so you don’t need an extra app.
> Record with sound from your mic, your device or both.

Considering Samsung releases new OS updates relatively fast, I'll just wait until December 2020 or so in order to update the Android version and then won't have to uncomfortably download an app from the store for this job.

Answer (score 1):

You can install a screen recorder app from google play store. There are many different ones available. Just do a search on "screen recorder".

For instances,

- [ADV Screen Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blogspot.byterevapps.lollipopscreenrecorder)
- [AZ Screen Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hecorat.screenrecorder.free)
- [Mobizen Screen Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rsupport.mvagent)
- [Screen Recorder & Video Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=videoeditor.videorecorder.screenrecorder)
- [Super Screen Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tianxingjian.screenshot)

Comment: Do you trust these apps to the point of installing them?

Comment: I will not take responsibility for your installing them. But they are no different then other apps. If you read the reviews and see its around for a while and many people have tried it. That should say something. (There is one with over 100,000,000 downloads and is editors choice.)